# Windows hangs when closing lid, how do I diagnose?

Tags: windows-xp, freeze

This is a Lenovo Z565 which originally came with Windows 7, and I downgraded it to XP.

As soon as I close the lid, Windows freezes instantly and doesn't respond to any input. The screen stays on, and the cursor moves but doesn't click. very weird. I have to do a hard shutdown after this.

The same also happens when hibernate is the selected action on lid closing.

What's more annoying is that I have found no standby error on the event log. I don't think I am missing any drivers, device manager doesn't show anything missing. It's also worth noting that it doesn't happen when I select "Standby" from the Start menu.

Any ideas on solving or diagnosing it?

Answer (score 0):

Since the same thing **doesn't** happen when you sleep/hibernate from the start menu then I'd blame it on hardware.

It doesn't sound like there is anything you can do from an OS standpoint.

Comment: Maybe, but since i don't remember it happening on Win7, i think it may be driver related, not hardware.